# awk to lookup value using specific fields in another file

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk`to find all the `$3` values in `file2` that are between `$2` and `$3` in `file1`. If a value in `$3` of `file2` is between the `file1` fields then it is printed along with the `$6` value in `file1`. Both `file1` and `file2` are `tab-delimited` as well as the desired output. If there is nothing to print then the next line is processed. The `awk` below is close but using my actual `~30MB` file it processes slow and prints in aan unexpected format. I am not sure how to adjust either. Thank you :).

**file1**

```
chr1    948953  948956  chr1:948953-948956  .   ISG15
chr1    949363  949858  chr1:949363-949858  .   ISG15
chr1    955542  955763  chr1:955542-955763  .   AGRN
chr1    957570  957852  chr1:957570-957852  .   AGRN
chr1    976034  976270  chr1:976034-976270  .   AGRN
```

**file2**

```
rs13303106  1   891945  GG
rs28415373  1   893981  CC
rs13303010  1   894573  AA
rs6696281   1   903104  CC
rs28391282  1   904165  GG
rs6657048   1   957640  CC
rs2710888   1   959842  CT
rs3128126   1   962210  AG
rs2710875   1   977780  CT
rs4511111   1   949375  GG
```

**current output**

```
rs6657048   1   957640  CC  
4   AGRN
rs4511111   1   949375  GG  
2   ISG15
```

**desired output**

```
rs6657048   1   957640  CC  AGRN
rs4511111   1   949375  GG  ISG15
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '                   
NR == FNR {min[NR]=$2; max[NR]=$3; Gene[NR]=$NF; next}
{                
    for (id in min) 
        if (min[id] < $3 && $3 < max[id]) {
            print $0, id, Gene[id]
            break              
        }
}                                     
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files contain control-Ms so `print $0` is wrapping onto the next line. Run dos2unix or similar on them first and then just don't include `, id` in the print statement if you don't want the `id` printed.